# Htaccess only home page https://a.com to https://www.a.com redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

My htaccess (codeigniter)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On       

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

if visitor open main page https://example.com need to redirect -> https://www.example.com

But i have already redirect for my links. I need to do together current codes.

How can i do?

Edit 1:

> this is i want:
>
> https://example.com -> https://www.example.com , 
>   https://example.com/somepage -> https://example.com/somepage (No
>   change) , https://www.example.com/otherpage.html -> https://example.com/otherpage.html (No use www redirected)
>
> Only the main page will use www. tag
>
> All other page not use www.

Comment: What, you are redirecting from `https://www.example.com/somepage` to `https://example.com/somepage` already, but only for the main page you want this _the other way around_? Why, what would be the purpose of that?

Comment: Yes. Because google i buy a domain but this domain get dmca to mainpage before me.

I need to only redirect main page for appear again google search.

Comment: _“but this domain get dmca to mainpage before me”_ - no clue what that word salad is supposed to mean. But if you need to only redirect main page, then set the pattern of the RewriteRule accordingly, so that it matches an _empty_ path - `^$`

Comment: this is i want:

https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com/somepage -> https://example.com/somepage (No change)
https://www.example.com/otherpage.html -> https://example.com/otherpage.html (No change)

Only the main page will use www. tag

All other page not use www.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it does not work.
I updated my question. Can you look again?

Comment: I tried to achieve what you said. But since apache gives limited options in rewriting, could n`t get this working. How ever this scenario always falls in to a loop in all try outs

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RedirectMatch` to achive your goal.

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 https://example.com https://www.example.com
```